# Excel and VBA regarding shapes

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I'm working on some experiments and I've run across something I'd like to do that I cannot figure out.

I would like to allow for a user to click a shape on an Excel spreadsheet that lets the user keep the shape highlighted so they can move it with the arrow keys, but when they click the shape, the VBA code fills in a field with an integer and fills the same field with a different integer if a different shape is selected by the user. The whole time keep in mind, I would like for the user to still have control of the shape on the spreadsheet.

Might anybody be able to help me figure this one out? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to implement.  There is a macro associated with the Shape.  You click the Shape and the macro runs.  Say the macro is like:

```
Sub HelloWorld()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

We introduce a global Boolean called *MoveMode*
If *MoveMode* is False, the macro runs as usual, but if *MoveMode* is True, then the Shape is Selected and can be moved with the ARROW keys.

```
Public MoveMode As Boolean

Sub HelloWorld()
    If MoveMode Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Select
    Else
        MsgBox "Hello World"
    End If
End Sub
```

Now all we need a a little sub to change *MoveMode:*

```
Sub MAIN()
    MoveMode = Not MoveMode
End Sub
```

Comment: When I implemented this, it does not allow me to place the Public MoveMode As Boolean. It demands that that line of code not go above the Sub Active() line.

It says, "Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property."

Comment: **You must place the standalone *Dim*  ABOVE all the subs in a module**

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've written out everything as you've presented it, but when I click the shape, while it does do what the code outlines it to do (fill in a cell with an integer), it does not keep the shape selected to be moved by the user.

Comment: I figured it out I think. Right now the first click fills in a field with a number and the second click selects the shape. I wish I could find a way to do both without having to double click.

Comment: After some additional experimentation I was able to figure out exactly what I needed. I wouldn't have been able to figure it out without Gary's Student help. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad you have a solution